# Icons not loading after created new theme in sylius

Tags: sylius

After I created a theme in sylius my icons are not loading. But when I include the original path of style.css they appear. What am I doing wrong.

I have followed this link as a reference:

[How to add CSS files on a Sylius theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494418/how-to-add-css-files-on-a-sylius-theme).

[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbLZv.png)

Comment: Can you clarify what "not loading" means? What does the network console tell you about this?

Comment: Some code appears in place of the icon. Network console is not showing anything.

Comment: Okay. "Some code". Then I would guess that there is "some error" in your code. But as you have not yet shared any code nor the difference between the original CSS file and yours, noone can help to spot that error

Comment: I have attached a screenshot. Please have a look at it.

Comment: That screenshot does not contain any code

Comment: Can you see three boxes in place of icons, above privacy policy link?

Comment: Yes, I can. But I cannot guess why there are three boxes. Most probably: there is an error in the code. My hint: fix that error. If you need any help in fixing that code, show the code

Comment: I have changed the source path of style.css file because I have created my own theme. Both the default css and theme css files are same instead of some minor changes. {% include '@SyliusUi/_stylesheets.html.twig' with {'path': 'bundles/syliusshop/style.css'} %}

Comment: In network console. its showing 404 for icon files.

Comment: So, then the error is obvious

Comment: Yeah, got it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the style.css file in your theme folder. Change the src url of the icons in @font-face.

For example:

Add `fonts/icons.eot`instead of `themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.eot`

Do the same thing for every font file and images.